# Why can't I access my Joomla dashboard after changing my .htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

So basically, I modified my `.htaccess` file, and now I cannot login to my Joomla dashboard.

I can enter my username and password, although once I click 'login', the page basically just refreshes itself and does not go to the dashboard/administrator section. The login page for Joomla (incase you don't know) is www.mydomain.com/administrator.

I was editing the file to remove all the errors and temporary redirects it was giving. I received my error report from this page http://www.ragepank.com/redirect-check/. So somehow, I need to change my file to allow me to still login, and to also eliminate all errors.

I know for a fact that it is the `.htaccess` file since when I remove it from my server, I can login perfectly fine.

I went through and removed things bit by bit to see which part was messing it all up. So here is the culprit:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(m)\.candocarloans\.com\.au$
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.candocarloans.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Here is my full `.htaccess` file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive on
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 30 days"
    </IfModule>
    Header unset ETag
    FileETag None
</FilesMatch>

#####################################################
#  READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that disallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
#
#####################################################

##  Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

#
#  mod_rewrite in use
RewriteEngine On

#  Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
#  is not directly related to physical file paths.
#  Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root)
RewriteBase /

# Check if mobile=1 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=1(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST}]

# Check if mobile=0 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 0
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:0:%{HTTP_HOST}]

# cookie can't be set and read in the same request so check
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [S=1]

# Check if this looks like a mobile device
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$

# Check if we're not already on the mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie}        !\mobile=0(;|$)
# Now redirect to the mobile site
RewriteRule ^ http://m.candobikeloans.com.au%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# Redirect to www if not www.domain or m.domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(m)\.candobikeloans\.com\.au
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.candobikeloans\.com\.au
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.candotruckloans.com.au/$1 [R=301,L] 

# If it ends with index.php and is not m.domain redirect to www.domain.com/content
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(m)\.candobikeloans\.com\.au$
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.candobikeloans.com.au/$1 [R=301,L] 

# Redirect all variations of index and default to www.domain.com/
# exception of index.php which should not be redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(default|index)\.(s?html?|pl|aspx?|cfm)[\s]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [R=301,L]

########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to set a mosConfig value through the URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode crap to send via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
#
########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits

########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
#
########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section
```

Comment: download a copy of Joomla and replace the **.htaccess** file you changed with a fresh one.

Comment: @Lodder - That wouldn't help me much since I need my modified version. My modified version contains mobile and tablet redirects along with some 404 redirects. The default Joomla `.htaccess` would do me no good.

Comment: You should do what I suggested above, then add each change you made for mobile and tablet redirects one by one and test them

Comment: @Lodder - I found the part that is messing everything up. I added it to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably prevent the administrator URLs from being rewritten.

Do so by adding another condition to that chain:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/administrator/
```

Comment: Great solution. Although, above what rule should I add this?